# About Removing the duplicate CSV files or rows from bigquery Table

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I created a table in BigQuery In Cloud Application . By mistake I uploaded two csv files in a bigquery Table. 
         How to delete either one or both csv file from bigquery table?

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to remove data from a BigQuery table.  Your best option is to re-import the data in a new table.  (If you no longer have the original CSV, you can export the table and then remove the duplicates before re-importing.)